# Does Dovahzul have the same grammar rules as English, or are they different?

Tags: grammar, dovahzul

I have recently been reading [this page about the Dragon Language](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Alphabet), and I was curious about whether if it and the English language share grammer rules. They seem to have similar bases (organized alphabets with words that derive from it), but I am unsure since Dovahzul seems to be primitive.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of rules that are exactly the same.  For instance, Dovahzul has the [exact same parts of speech](https://www.thuum.org/learn/grammar/sentence-structure.php):

- Nouns
- Verbs
- Adjectives
- Adverbs
- Articles
- Conjunctions
- Interjections
- Prepositions

However, there are some rules that are different: for instance, in the Dragon Language, some words can be used either as an adjective, noun, verb, or adverb, such as the word [**Nahlot**](https://www.thuum.org/word.php?w=nahlot), which means officially "Silenced," but whose meaning can be expanded to mean "silent," "silently," or "silence."

So yes, it shares some rules with English, but no, its rules are not the same.  If you had any specific questions about specific rules, you'd have to ask those in separate questions.

Comment: Zero derivation is incredibly common in English, so I'm not sure that's much of a difference.